# How to compute current given voltage in a particular RC circuit with a voltage source and a current source

Tags: voltage, current, kirchhoffs-laws

I have troubles solving this simple circuit: I'd like to express \$I_b\$ in terms of \$V_{sig}\$ but I don't know where to start (\$V_{sig}\$ is AC, \$I_b\$ is DC). Could somebody give me a hint ?

[image: simple circuit]

Comment: You drew Ib as an independent current source. It's current is completely independent of Vsig and there's no way you can obtain a relationship between them from the information you've given.

Comment: There is no connection between Ib and Vsig anyway, since Ib is DC, anything it does is blocked by C1.  Ib can be completely removed from the circuit for the purpose of determining Vsig.

Comment: Might you be asking what the current through Rb is? If you are (ignoring the pointless dc current source), the current through Rb will be an ac current! More information needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an independent ideal current generator, its current is fixed to Ib and, since it's in DC, it's constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Ib is a independent current source, so its current will be what it wants it to be regardless of what the outside world is doing, *by definition*.

Another issue is that you say Ib is DC.  For DC analisys, you can replace all capacitors with opens.  The only thing connected to Ib then, for the sake of DC analisys, is Rb.  This is known as a Norton source, which can be trivially converted to a Thevenin source.  Sometimes one or the other is more illuminating to a human observer, but both are indistiguishable from the point of view of the rest of the circuit.